# Xpath Injection detection tool

Tags: xpath, code-injection

I am working on XPath Injection attack, so looking forward to build a tool to detect XPath Injection in a website. Is web crawling and scanning used for this?
What can be the logic to detect it?

Are there any **open source tools** to detect it, so that i can develop it in Java by looking at logic used in that code.

Answer (score 1):

WebCruiser Web Vulnerability Scanner include an XPath Injection Tool inside.